Is the set $C^{n}([a, b])$ a normed algebra with the pointwise product and the sum of suprema norm?
Given the pointwise product $\cdot$ in $C^{n}([a, b])$, and the norm $\lVert \hspace{0.2 cm} \rVert$ defined for any $n$-times continuosly differentiable function $h$ whose domain is $[a, b]$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\lVert h \rVert = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\Big\lVert h^{(k)} \Big\rVert_{\infty}}\text{,}
\end{equation*}
I am being asked to show that the pair $(C^{n}([a, b]), \hspace{0.05 cm}\cdot\hspace{0.1 cm})$ is a normed algebra.
So far, I have been able to show that $(C^{n}([a, b])$ is an algebra, but I am finding myself unable to provide a proof regarding the submultiplicativity of the norm $\lVert \hspace{0.2 cm} \rVert$:
Let $f$ and $g$ be some functions of class $C^{n}([a, b])$, and let $F_{k}$ and $G_{k}$ denote the uniform norm of the $k$-th derivative of $f$ and $g$, respectively, for any nonnegative integer $k$ less or equal than $n$.
\begin{align*}
\lVert f \cdot g \rVert &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\Big\lVert (f \cdot g)^{(k)}\Big\rVert_{\infty}}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\Bigg\lVert\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}f^{k - j} \cdot g^{j}}\Bigg\rVert}\\
&\leq \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j} \Big\lVert f^{(k - j)}\Big\rVert_{\infty}\Big\lVert g^{(j)}\Big\rVert_{\infty}}}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{\binom{k}{j}F_{k - j}G_{j}}}\\
&= \text{(...)}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\sum_{j = 0}^{n - k}{\binom{k + j}{j}F_{k}G_{j}}}\\
&\stackrel{\text{?}}{\leq} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}F_{k}G_{j}}\\
&= \text{(...)}\\
&= \lVert f \rVert \lVert g \rVert
\end{align*}
These last lines summarise my best attempt to come up with a proof, but, as you can see, there is one inequality that needs a proper justification. Other attemps involve the use of the principle of induction.
I am led to believe that $\lVert \hspace{0.2 cm} \rVert$ is not defined correctly, and that it should be
\begin{equation*}
\lVert h \rVert = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\dfrac{\big\lVert h^{(k)} \big\rVert_{\infty}}{k!}} \forall h \in C^{n}([a, b])
\end{equation*}
instead.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

I haven't checked every one of your arguments, but maybe induction is easier

I think you are right in thinking that the norm is not defined correctly:
Take $[a,b]=[0,1]$, $n=4$ and $f(x)=\exp(x)$. Then
$$
\|f\|=5e, \quad \|f^2\|=31e^2 > 25e^2=\|f\|^2. 
$$

I love the simplicity of all the arguments underlying this counterexample, and I find it astounding how the inequality failed even with such a nice function on such a nice domain.
Thank you very much! I really had a good time reading your counterexample!
